# Nuxt static site - where is the markup?

Tags: seo, nuxt.js, static-site

I've set the mode to static and ran npm run generate. The site is being served from the /dist/ directory, but where is the markup when I view the source? view-source:https://eosnomad.com/

I don't think I'm getting the SEO benefits here since Google doesn't see HTML. I only see the source code when looking in dev tools. Am I doing this wrong?

Here is my nuxt configuration:

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  head: {
    title: process.env.DOMAIN,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content:
          process.evn.CONTENT,
      },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  css: [],

  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/cookie-law', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-agile', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-js-modal', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-formulate', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-the-mask', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/route-to-hash', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/global-components', mode: 'client' },
  ],

  components: true,

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseSiteTitle: '${DOMAIN}',
    siteID: '${WORDPRESS_SITE_ID}',
    cmsEndpoint: process.env.IS_LOCAL
      ? 'https://dashboard${TLD_LOCAL}/${WORDPRESS_SITE_SLUG}/${WORDPRESS_ACF_ENDPOINT}'
      : 'https://dashboard${TLD}/${WORDPRESS_SITE_SLUG}/${WORDPRESS_ACF_ENDPOINT}',
    newsEndpoint: process.env.IS_LOCAL
      ? 'https://dashboard${TLD_LOCAL}/wp-json/getnews?property_id=${WORDPRESS_SITE_ID}'
      : 'https://dashboard${TLD}/wp-json/getnews?property_id=${WORDPRESS_SITE_ID}',
  },

  tailwindcss: {
    exposeConfig: true,
  },

  loading: false,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    [
      '@teamnovu/nuxt-breaky',
      {
        enabled: true,
        enableInProd: false,
        colorScheme: 'auto',
        position: 'bottomRight',
      },
    ],
  ],

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/svg',
    'nuxt-fontawesome',
    '@nuxtjs/dayjs',
    ['vue-scrollto/nuxt', { duration: 1000, easing: 'ease-in-out' }],
  ],

  dayjs: {
    plugins: ['isSameOrAfter', 'isSameOrBefore'],
  },

  fontawesome: {
    imports: [
      {
        set: '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
        icons: [
          'faBullhorn',
          'faSortUp',
          'faSortDown',
          'faUtensils',
          'faEnvelopeOpenText',
          'faArrowLeft',
          'faArrowRight',
          'faTimesCircle',
        ],
      },
      {
        set: '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
        icons: ['faFacebookSquare', 'faTwitterSquare', 'faInstagram'],
      },
    ],
  },

  webfontloader: {
    typekit: {
      id: 'XXXX',
    },
  },

  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      shouldPreload: (file, type) => {
        return ['script', 'style', 'font'].includes(type)
      },
    },
  },

  // Axios module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios)
  axios: {},

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {},
}
```

Comment: Try to inspect and find why you do have a `noscript`, looks like it's coming from GTM.

Comment: What does this have to do with missing HTML markup?

Comment: That it's not rendered because the browser only have the choice of a `noscript` tag with an iframe coming from your GTM. Since it looks like it's the final thing that is generated, you do not have any static markup before the hydration. Double check if you have it locally and maybe try to disable GTM.

Comment: I cut the tags out and still the same issue. All of the content on this is coming from a fetch API call. 

I created another nuxt site and this one has hard coded content: https://licrentregulated.com/. Could that be the issue? That an API call is driving the content so the markup is not there?

Comment: Depends on what the API returns and how it is supposed to work yeah. Did you read the documentation for this one ?

Comment: I saw nothing in the documentation about API driven data not displaying in the DOM after nuxt generate. I’m stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This is a single page website and I put all the components in the default layout file. In order to generate static markup properly it all needs to be in the index.vue file.